# Cat 2 files and avoid duplication of lines

Tags: shell, sed, grep, awk, cat

I have the **file1** with the following content

```
{"name":"clio5", "value":"13"}
{"name":"citroen_c4", "value":"23"}
{"name":"citroen_c3", "value":"12"}
{"name":"golf4", "value":"16"}
{"name":"golf3", "value":"8"}
```

And I have the **file2** with the following content

```
{"name":"clio5", "value":"14"}
{"name":"citroen_c4", "value":"25"}
{"name":"golf4", "value":"18"}
```

I want to execute a shell command in order to display the content of the **file1** and the **file2**. if a `name` exist in both **file1** and **file2** so I want to display only the related line of the **file2**.

So the output should look like this:

```
$command taking account file1 file2
{"name":"clio5", "value":"14"}
{"name":"citroen_c4", "value":"25"}
{"name":"citroen_c3", "value":"12"}
{"name":"golf4", "value":"18"}
{"name":"golf3", "value":"8"}
```

The command should not edit **file1** neither **file2**

The command should be as simple as possible

The command could contains `grep`, `sed`, `awk`

Comment: Is this [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)? (Your examples are quite close, but not exact; the commas separating the value sets are missing.) If you only wanted to avoid printing duplicate lines, `uniq` would do fine, but this appears to be more than that.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling And if it is json, there would be much more useful tools to operate on the date probably.

Answer (score 3):

This does not preserve the order of the lines, but that was not a requirement

```
awk '{line[$1]=$0} END {for (key in line) print line[key]}' file1 file2
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next};$1 in a {$0=a[$1]}; 1' file2 file1
{"name":"clio5", "value":"14"}
{"name":"citroen_c4", "value":"25"}
{"name":"citroen_c3", "value":"12"}
{"name":"golf4", "value":"18"}
{"name":"golf3", "value":"8"}
```

That assumes that `file2` only *updates* entries that are already found in `file1`. If `file2` may insert new entries, you may want to change it to:

```
awk -F, '
  NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}
  $1 in a {$0=a[$1];delete a[$1]}
  1
  END{for (i in a) print a[i]}' file2 file1
```

The order in which the *inserted*  entries are displayed is unspecified. The above assumes there's only one entry per *name* in each file.

Answer (score 1):

If order is not important, these commands should do it:

```
cat file2 file1 > files
cut -f2 -d: files | cut -f1 -d, | sort | uniq > pat
for i in $(cat pat); do grep $i files -m 1; done
```

The first command joins the input files (order is important; file2 goes first because its values will override the ones in file1).

The second command cuts the car brands from the input files, sorts and removes duplicates, and stores them in the `pat` file.

The third command greps each pattern on the combined input file and stops on the first match, so if the same car brand appears on both files, only the one in file2 is printed.

If order is important and all the patterns are in file1, you can use just file1 in the second command (instead of files) and omit the `sort` and `uniq` commands.

Comment: Instead of making a temporary file, you can pipe to a loop: `...sort | uniq | while read i ; do...`. Also, you can pipe the output of `cat` to `cut`: `cat file2 file1 | cut -f2 -d: | ...`.

Comment: @EvanTeitelman, Thanks. I imagined there would be a more compact way, but I feared it would be less readable.